# Why is the combination formula (without replacement) not just $\frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - r + 1)}{r!}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Why is the combination formula (without replacement) not just $\frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - r + 1)}{r!}$?

I tried many examples. Both the title formula and the standard combination formula gave the same answers. At first, I thought it was because of something about $\binom{n}{r}$ and $\binom{n}{n - r}$, but those examples didn't seem to matter.

Ex: from $\binom{5}{2}$, from $\binom{5}{3}$ gave the same answers from both formulas and  from $\binom{20}{17}$, from $\binom{20}{3}$ gave the same answers from both formulas)

Comment: What's the question?  Are you just asking if $\frac {n!}{(n-r)!}=n\times (n-1)\times \cdots \times (n-r+1)$?  If so, the answer is, yes.  Those are equal.

Comment: @Lulu I mean I tried just using n * (n-1) * (n-2) until (n-r+1) for the numerator then just divided it by r!  and that gave me the same answers as the general combination formula that looks more complicated. I'm wondering why don't people just use the simpler one that I mentioned.

Comment: Sure, so that's the same thing I wrote. It's easy to see that they are equivalent, so there's no reason to prefer one to the other.  Note that you could also have used $\frac {n!}{r!}=n\times (n-1)\times \cdots \times (r+1)$ and rewritten the standard expression using that.    In any case, you are correct in thinking that you should always compute using as few multiplies and divides as possible.

Comment: @Lulu thanks, the confusion is mainly why the standard combination formula that I see taught is the more complicated one. Maybe it's just some tradition?

Comment: As an expression, it's quite simple and easy to remember, and it makes the symmetry $\binom nr=\binom n{n-r}$ (i.e.  "the number of ways to choose $r$ objects out of $n$ is the same as the number of ways to choose $n-r$ objects out $n$") visible.  But there's no harm if you prefer one of the equivalent expressions.

Comment: Because it's shorter to write $\frac {n!}{(n-r)!}$ than to write $n\times (n-1) \times .... \times (n-r+1)$.  Much shorter.  And $\frac {n!}{(n-r)!} = n\times (n-1) \times .... \times (n-r+1)$ is such a basic, well-known, and clearly obvious equation that consider them to be equivalent is natural.... In a way its similar to knowing that $m$ is an even number we can write the number which multiplied by $2$ as $\frac m2$ rather than the "direct and simpler" $d$ s.t. $2d = m$.

Comment: @fleablood the one I see for combinations a lot is n! / (n-k)! k!

Comment: I didn't mention without replacement but have edited the title.

Comment: $\frac {n!}{(n-k)!k!} = \frac {n\times (n-1)\times ...... (n-k + 1)}{k!}$.  Now do you think $\frac {n\times (n-1)\times ...... (n-k + 1)}{k!}$ is "simpler" than $\frac {n!}{(n-k)!k!}$?  Maybe it is in that the *concept* of $n\choose k$ is "you have the choices from $n$ down to but not including $n-k$ and we divide by $k!$" but what is the *notation* for that and how do we express it.  Well as $n!$ is all the way down from $n$ and $(n-k)!$ is all the way down from $n-r$ then $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ is all the way from $n$ but stopping at $n-k$.  Is that really more complicated?

Comment: Why all the algebra? If you pick three things out of twenty, then aren't each of the seventeen things you didn't pick a choice? How many of those are there? It seems to me that each time you pick three, you pick seventeen and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Great question! The answer is that mathematicians know and love **both** formulas, and will use whichever one is convenient for the purpose at hand. (It is amazingly useful to have alternative expressions for the same quantity; that's why we spend so much time learning identities.)

The formula $$C(n,r)=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$ has the advantage of being concise and easy to remember, and of making it plain to see that $C(n,r)=C(n,n-r)$; it generalizes to the *multinomial* formula $$C(n;r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k)=\frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_k!};\ r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_k=n.$$

On the whole, your formula $$C(n,r)=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$$
is the better of the two. First, it's easier to compute, though for computation the form $$C(n,r)=\frac n1\times\frac{n-1}2\times\frac{n-2}3\times\cdots\times\frac{n-r+1}r$$ may be even better. More importantly, your formula makes it apparent that $C(n,r)$ makes sense even when $n$ is not a natural number; for example, $$C(n,3)=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6=\frac16n^3-\frac12n^2+\frac13n$$ is just a cubic polynomial, defined for all real (or complex) values of $n$. Of course such generalized "combination numbers" as $C(-\frac12,r)$ are not useful for counting poker hands, but they are just what you need if you want to use the Binomial Theorem to expand a binomial with a negative or fractional exponent, such as $$(1+x)^{-\frac12}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty C(-\frac12,r)x^r=1-\frac12x+\frac38x^2-\frac5{16}x^3+\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree that if one is learning elementary stuff then for most of the times instead of $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, the equivalent formula $\displaystyle\frac{n⋅(n-1)⋅(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$ comes much more handy.

***Example:***

1. $^8C_5=\binom85=\binom83=\displaystyle\frac{8⋅7⋅6}{1⋅2⋅3}=56\quad$ which is easier than: $\quad\displaystyle\frac{8!}{5!3!}=\frac{40320}{(120)(6)}$

Obviously that's why one is also taught the properties (such as one you already observed) to make such tasks easier like: $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}; \ \binom nr+\binom n{r-1}=\binom{n+1}r; \ $ etc.

---

***But*** once we move onto stuff like calculating $\displaystyle\binom{43}{26}$ now I would rather prefer the former over latter because, first, it's neat, second, latter isn't really helpful. 
Other cases may be like: $\displaystyle\frac{26!}{7!8!8!}$, etc.

---

Surprisingly though I often see that some students don't see that the latter may be derived from former and thus would instead eveytime expand the numerator to be surprised to see something "big" getting cancelled from the denominator. Funny but sad too and add to that some confident teachers who are too sure of their students' ability to observe these things. Unlike you though, many don't. They'll basically always solve in this way: $$\displaystyle\binom85=\binom83=\frac {8!}{5!3!} \ (\text{LOL})= \frac{8.7.6.5!}{5!3!}=\frac{8.7.6}{6}=56 $$